# PHP: Wrong evaluation in switch code

Tags: php

**PREAMBLE: $state can have 3 possible values:**

- 1) `0` (zero , int)
- 2) `'Set Level: 10 %'` (string)
- 3) `'Set Level: 20 %'`
  (string)

I have a switch code that doesn't return right value.

This is the code:

```
<?php

$state = 0;

switch ($state) {

            case 'Set Level: 10 %':

                $return = 1;

            break;

            case 'Set Level: 20 %':

                $return = 2;

            break;

            default:

                $return = 0;

            break;

        }

        echo 'return:';

        var_dump($return);
```

And this is the fiddle: https://3v4l.org/IQ142

With `$state = 0` it returns `1` and not `0`, as default. I did try also to remove default and impose case 0: but no change.

Thank you

NOTICE: `$state` could be also as string. For this I need to check for string.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski How do you know OP isn't possibly passing a string to the switch?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yes, which should default as it's not a string, but it doesn't.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton We are forced to assume $state is an integer since the OP doesn't state what $state is being passed in as.

Comment: @clearshot66 Why would you assume it's an integer when the switch itself shows strings?

Comment: Why initiate something as 0 if you don't intend it to be numeric?

Comment: Define $state = '0';

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I did add 2 explain

Comment: Long story short, PHP will cast strings to integers, resulting in `0` when comparing. Your input `$state` must be a string type to avoid the cast and incorrect comparison. It cannot be an int.  `echo 0 == "any string"` prints 1.

Comment: Demo: https://3v4l.org/v4qL9

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I did add an explain. Thank you, but I need to check also the strings.

Comment: If int 0 is valid input, why not cast it to a string, make it a case, put it first and don't rely on the default?

Comment: But of course you can force a cast to string, and get the result you want: `switch ((string)$state)`.

Comment: ^^ Yes. Force `$state` to be a string before allowing it to pass into the switch. That should solve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not compare an int with a string. Before sending the `$state` to the `switch` do a conversion to string. This will give you the correct result.

```
$state = 0;

switch((string)$state)
...
```